# How to load jQuery assets before blocks and regions

Tags: 8, javascript

I need a jQuery script to load **immediately** before a certain block shows on my Drupal 8 front page. I'm trying to use the following but I get 'TypeError $ is not a function' in code inspector. Here's my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slideshow").zAccordion({
        ...code...
  });
});
```

The problem is the first line. In Drupal 8 what is the preferred way to write this script to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap the javascript to avoid namespace conflicts.

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slideshow").zAccordion({
        ...code...
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```